# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str in list problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
book_title =  ['great', 'expectations','the', 'adventures', 'of', 'sherlock','holmes','the','great','gasby','hamlet','adventures','of','huckleberry','fin']
word_counter = []
for words in book_title:
    if words not in word_counter:
        word_counter[words]=1
    else:
        word_counter[words]+=1
```

i am getting type of error want correction should i do to improve this

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: You need to create a dictionary instead of list to keep the word count

Comment: You may need a dict.`word_counter = {}`.

Comment: Or just: `word_counter = Counter(book_title)`

Comment: Please provide full traceback

Answer (score 3):

As others noted, you are conceptually trying to use a dictionary, not a list. However, for counting, there is a specialized dictionary, [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which you can use as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

word_counter = Counter(book_title)
```

which does the same much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary to count the words. Better to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to do this.

```
from collections import defaultdict

book_title =  ['great', 'expectations','the', 'adventures', 'of', 'sherlock','holmes','the','great','gasby','hamlet','adventures','of','huckleberry','fin']
word_counter = defaultdict(int)
for word in book_title:
    word_counter[word] += 1
```

Comment: If you're using the collections module, it's actually better to use Counter, I think.

Comment: Yeah right, I suppose this could be useful as well in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
book_title =  ['great', 'expectations','the', 'adventures', 'of', 'sherlock','holmes','the','great','gasby','hamlet','adventures','of','huckleberry','fin']
word_counter = {} #use dict not list
for words in book_title:
    if words not in word_counter:
        word_counter[words]=1
    else:
        word_counter[words]+=1
```

Use a dictionary for key-value pairs. List only stores values. You trying to access the value by its key which is not possible in the list.

Pythonic way

```
from collections import Counter
book_title =  ['great', 'expectations','the', 'adventures', 'of', 'sherlock','holmes','the','great','gasby','hamlet','adventures','of','huckleberry','fin']
word_counter = Counter(book_title)
```